# Facebook page_engaged_users Period 'day'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am hitting Facebooks Graph API.

I am using the period of 'day' but it is return 2, 3, and 4 days ago.  Is it possible to get Yesterdays insights on `page_engaged_users`?

Comment: It would help if you showed some code. Also which gems, if any, are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [FB Graph API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights/#availmetrics) -

> Metrics that are marked with * are available in real-time, i.e., they are refreshed approximately every 15 minutes. Most other metrics will update once every 24 hours.

This leads me to believe that getting "yesterday's" data might not be possible  (or accurate).